# parsing URL ?a=b params with VB.NET from plain string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using a string to store key=value pairs, it has same format as QueryString

How can I easily parse it to array?  or can I somehow use interal class QueryString("paramname") to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
' parse to pairs
                Dim resultarray As Array = allresultdata.Split("&")
                Dim result1 As String
                Dim keyvals2 As Array
                For Each result1 In resultarray
                    keyvals2 = result1.Split()
                    keyvals.Set(keyvals2(0), keyvals2(1))
                Next
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx#), this will give you a `NameValueCollection`. You can then access your values easily

```
Dim keynameValue As String = nameValueCollection.Get("Keyname")
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Split()` probably will work for you....

Answer (score 0):

> or can I somehow use interal class
>   QueryString("paramname") to access it?

If you need to access querystring from another class other then page code behind, use this :

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("parameterName")
```